# Adding virtual keys

Tags: javascript, arrow-keys

Can we add virtual keys to a snake game website, like that website we can only play on the laptop because the phone doesn't have arrow up, arrow down, etc keys. So I am asking can we add virtual keys to this website -> https://prashoon123.github.io/SnakeGame/
with the help of javascript?

Comment: so, HTML buttons perhaps? yes, HTML does have button elements

Comment: This seems like a yes/no question (the answer is yes BTW), you might want to check out how do I ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Yes you can add virtual keys, and then trigger the event types, that would normally be sent by your computer, manually.

Check the keycode data here:
https://keycode.info/

and to dispatch the event:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'a'}));
```

And you need to use the `<element>.addEventListener` to listen for det keydowns.

Keydown documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

--

If the idea is to support mobile browsers, you can instead use the `touchstart` and `touchend` events.

Based on the start and end values (x,y positions) - you can calculate if the user swiped in any direction.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event

Comment: You might want to check https://keyjs.dev, which includes some explanations of things like Alt Codes and virtual/mobile keyboards and will soon include information about cross-browser inconsistencies! 